# Call JS Function after User clicks Like

Tags: 2013, document-library, rating, like

I have Ratings enabled on a document library in the form of Likes. I want to call a JS function after the user hits Like / Unlike but what I have isn't working.

```
var _href = $("a:contains('Like')").attr("href");
$("a:contains('Like')").attr("href", _href + 'javascript:CallMe();');

function CallMe() {
    alert('got here');
}
```

This renders the link as:

```
<a class="ms-secondaryCommandLink" id="likesElement-8" href="javascript:;javascript:CallMe();">
```

The alert never fires. How do I properly call a function after the Like JS has fired? Either Async or Sync would be suitable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$("a:contains('Like')").click(function(){CallMe()});
```

Jquery will stack the calls so the original click function is also called. [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: This also seems to be appending a click event so the function gets called multiple times. Any way to clear the click first then set it?

Comment: Use `$("a:contains('Like')").unbind('click');` to remove click event handlers and then set it again.